Change neovim :terminal behavior to vim
I just switched to neovim from vim due to the telescope plugin, but I don't like the way neovim handles terminals. Is there a way to change the behavior of the neovim :terminal command to the standard vim behavior: Open a terminal buffer in a new split in termminal mode, ready to enter commands. I'm using NVIM v0.6.1.
I'm sure there hast to be a simple fix to it in the init.vim, but I don't know how. And when I open a terminal the buffer description is a cryptic "term://~/.config/nvim//161148:/bin/bash "

The terminal feature is implemented differently in each editor. Read :help :terminal for how to customize it.

You may use this command:
:bo terminal
Or if you want it in a vertical split:
:vert bo terminal.
You'd still need to type "i" or "a" to be able to type in your command.But this could be taken care of in a key mapping:
A line in your init.vim could be:
nnoremap <leader>t :bo terminal<cr>a
... or in a lua file:
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>t', ':bo terminal<cr>a'),

I'm using zsh and have a similar strange buffer "name". No idea if this can be changed in any way.
